# Where do $POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR and $POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT come from?

Tags: docker

I am trying docker postgres by following the official postgres image on https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ .

In the document it run the following commands and get it to work:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
docker run -it --link some-postgres:postgres --rm postgres sh -c 'exec psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U postgres'
```

So my question is where do $POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT and $POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR come from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are made available to the second container you start via the Docker linking mechanisms.

From https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#environment-variables:

> When two containers are linked, Docker will set some environment
>   variables in the target container to enable programmatic discovery of
>   information related to the source container.
>
> ...
>
> The pattern followed is:
>   ...
>
> - *PORT*__ADDR will contain just the IP address from the URL (e.g. WEBDB_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.82).
> - *PORT*__PORT will contain just the port number from the URL (e.g. WEBDB_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT=8080).

Comment: Uh, I missclick downvoted and can't undo it :/ Any mod can help plz?